# This geometry nodes animation looks different when imported as ABC into another file?

Tags: export, import, alembic

I followed this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGxNuS_-bpo

and when I exported the file as alembic and imported into a new blender file or new maya file or any other software, it came up like this:

[image]

[image]

Why is this error happening? How to export this animation properly?

Here’s the file for reference:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X0zOcVhsEmfTq1z0AlZ4C8ggflYC34Fp/view?usp=sharing